# display progress dialog when touching item on list view

Tags: android, listview, progressdialog

I have a list view and I want that when I touching items on the list view my progress dialog opens and show loading message.
everything is ok but when I touching the items to see dialog my app crashing.but if I scrolling the list and after that touching the items my app Does give an error.
I dismiss the dialog in the next activity when data collected from network and displayed.

here is my listview fill cod

```
 public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<RssParser.Item> adapter, final RssParser.Item item, final int position)
    {

        try
        {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RecruitmentActivity.handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ActivityFirst.dismissLoadingDialog();
                            txtTitle.setText(item.title);
                            txtDate.setText(item.pubDate);
                            txt_time.setText(item.time);
                            txtDescription.setText(item.description);
                            layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            if (progress == null) {
                                                progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
                                                progress.setTitle("title");
                                                progress.setMessage("loading");
                                                progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                                progress.setCancelable(false);
                                            }
                                            progress.show();
                                            G.SelectedApplication = item;
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, Adapter_Description.class)
                                                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            intent.putExtra("INPUT", item.link + "");
                                            intent.putExtra("INPUT_DESC", item.description + "");
                                            G.context.startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    });
                }
            });

            thread.start();
```

this is my dismiss method

```
public static void dismissLoadingDialog() {

    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and this is my log

> 09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a65f2178 is not valid; is your activity running?
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):     **
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at **com.employment.app.find_work.recruitment.AdapterItems$ViewHolder$1$1$1.onClick(AdapterItems.java:89
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)**
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):**
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-07 20:44:23.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1461):
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You are using a Context which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: you are click on thread so its throw error. when user click pass data in Handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code click event code in

```
your_activity_name.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             if (progress == null) {
                        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
                        progress.setTitle("title");
                        progress.setMessage("loading");
                        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progress.setCancelable(false);
              }
              progress.show();
              G.SelectedApplication = item;
              Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, Adapter_Description.class)
                     .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              intent.putExtra("INPUT", item.link + "");
              intent.putExtra("INPUT_DESC", item.description + "");
              G.context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

put your code in run method.

Comment: i dont have an activity it's my class. my class is AdapterItem that extended in ArrayAdapter is it ok ?

Comment: @user3453159 yes its ok. pass your context in that context.runOnUiThread();

Comment: thank you so much but i'm new in android and still I have error plz look at my edited post.

Comment: @user3453159 you can use RecruitmentActivity.handler.post in onlick  method.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you "context" variable points to the **Activity** and not some other one.

2) Quite interesting, as in this case you should get "cannot touch view" exception, not a wrong window binder token exception.
It is possible that:

- Your application is already dead as stated (ie. past onPause() ).
- Due to the thread nesting mess you're touching UI controls outside the UI thread, which is the only one that can modify views. Try:
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)  {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          // Your code related to controlling the progress bar
      })
  }
  ```

  You could also use a handler to notify the views (which is actually more preferable)

3) Make sure to dismiss the dialog, before the old activity dies.